# IDEA does not see com.vaadin.Application

Tags: maven, client, vaadin

I am using `vaadin-bom` for importing vaadin dependencies, this one already has `vaadin-client-compiler` and other needed dependencies for using vaadin.
But when I extend my class from Application IDEA cant find the class

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the answer Application class is in Vaadin 6, for developing on client we need EntryPoint class